# Iphone Release Compile: how to trim down external library size?

Tags: iphone, ios, build

I am toying with an iphone app that usess opencv library, which is quite large. I barely use 1% of its features. Is there anyways to compile and bundle only the parts that I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source for the library, remove the files you don't need and aren't needed for compilation, then compile yourself.